# Hide div and store local storage not to show div on page refresh

Tags: html, onclick, local-storage

I have an image button in a div when click I want to hide image button and somehow store to local storage not to show div again on page refresh.

```
<div class="whatsapp"><a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/........." target="_blank">
<img src="/img/whatsapp_group.png" alt="Whatsapp Join Button"><div class="whatsappbut">To Find Out MORE!</div></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an ID(`id="img-btn"`) to your div to use it in script tag. If user didn't click on your image button so far, `localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')` will return null otherwise it'll return 'true'(as we set it in saveClicked function).
Just make sure to put the script tag before the body tag ends(or you can link a separated Javascript file).

```
<body>
  <div id="img-btn" class="whatsapp">
    <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/........." target="_blank">
      <img src="/img/whatsapp_group.png" alt="Whatsapp Join Button" />
      <div class="whatsappbut">To Find Out MORE!</div></a>
  </div>

  <script>
    checkImgBtnClicked();

    function checkImgBtnClicked() {
      const clicked = localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked'); // if this is not set it will return null
      if (clicked) {
        document.getElementById('img-btn').style.display = 'none'; // hides the img-btn
      } else {
        // add event listener for image button click(saveClicked function will be executed if user clicks on image button
        document.getElementById('img-btn').addEventListener('click', saveClicked);
      } 
    }

    function saveClicked() {
      // set a flag in local storage that image button is clicked
      localStorage.setItem('img-btn-clicked', 'true'); 
      document.getElementById('img-btn').style.display = 'none'; // hides the img-btn after it gets clicked
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, work 100% just one thing as I open a new tab target="_blank" the image is still showing until page refresh is there a way to refresh page on click and still open new tab

Comment: Yes. Just put document.getElementById('img-btn').style.display = 'none' inside the saveClicked function. This will hide the image after it gets clicked.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: On another note don't know if I must create a new post or on above example I want to show a hidden div in place of image button based on local storage with if statement  At the moment my statement is .... if ($CTA == '0' && WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE IF BUTTON WAS CLICKED){
         echo '<div class="footer hide">';
        }

Comment: I didn't fully understand your problem but any where you want to check if the button is clicked or not you should check the local storage. You can do this by `if (localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')){The code you write here will be executed if only image button is clicked already}`. The `checkImgBtnClicked` function will be executed every time the page loads and the `saveClicked` function will be executed every time the image button div is clicked. Based on what you want to do you can add the if statement to any of these functions.

Comment: I don't know how much I could help but if I didn't answer your question just leave comment again I'll try to answer again asap.

Comment: I need to check on everytime page load tried this but not working (need to hide div with class="overlay") I have put code below example code in own <script> tag  if (localStorage.getItem('checkImgBtnClicked')){
        echo '<div class="overlay hide">'

Comment: This is how you hide div with class "overlay".`if (localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')){document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = 'none';}`. querySelector selects the first element with class "overlay"

Comment: And if you want to add additional class name to overlay you can say: `document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('newClassName');`

Comment: Ok it is working but the opposite way I intended. My logic seems not to be right. First I check if ($Price == '1'){echo '<div class="overlay show">';} then what I want to achieve is that if  $Price =='1' and button click show overlay both conditions must met to show overlay

Comment: To show the overlay you do similar thing to hide the overlay: `document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = 'initial';`. This will reset the display and makes the overlay visible. And to check for both conditions you use and operator like this: `if(Price=='1' && localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')){document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = 'initial';}`. This will show the overlay if Price is equal to '1' and image button is clicked.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing it right but it's not working. I have class overlay set display: none in my css I used your code 
`if(Price=='1' && localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')){document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = 'initial';}` and remove the php code
`   if ($DropThePrice == '1'){
         echo '<div class="overlay show">';
        }`

Comment: I tried  `if(Price=='1' && localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')){document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = 'block';}` but class overlay not showing

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something or maybe you're doing something different but consider creating a new post or try to check your JS and HTML code in a completely separated file maybe that'll help find the problem because I have no idea what might be the problem here.

Comment: Thanx for your help will do that

Comment: I got it Price was php value had to convert to js value now working
`var Price = "<?php echo $Price ?>";
if (Price == '1' && localStorage.getItem('img-btn-clicked')){document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = 'initial';}`

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.